# Rails simple_form: How to disable error labels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to stop `simple_form` from adding error labels entirely.

tried the followign CSS:

```css
label.error { display:none; }
```

but `simple_form`'s JavaScript is setting the following rule when it's generated:

```css
display: block;
```

Am I missing a config that lets me turn off generation entirely?

This stops them from appearing, which works for now:

```css
label.error {
  display: none !important;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but SimpleForm doesn't use any javascript.

Answer (score 36):

Give this a try:

```
<%= f.input :password, error: false %>
```

[Source @ lib/simple_form/components/errors.rb](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/09c928f1c0b20ec19b82c52840e24204e5ab4ff4/lib/simple_form/components/errors.rb#L10)

If you want to disable for ALL fields, I believe you'd have to put this on all fields.

Comment: Perfect this does just what I want. The field is highlighted to indicate a problem, but no error message appears! Great.

Answer (score 3):

You can also disable labels, hints or error or configure the html of any of them:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :username, :label_html => { :class => 'my_class' } %>
    <%= f.input :password, :hint => false, :error_html => { :id => "password_error"} %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => false %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
```

For further reference check the link below:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable error messages on inputs site-wide, you can set this easily in the initialiser `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`:

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :default, class: :input,
    # Comment this line!
    #b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
  end
end
```

You will no longer see the validation messages beside every input.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 do the following to remove the hint underneath the input field and label from above

```
<%= f.input :password, required: true, label: false, hint: false %>
```